# How do I add 3rd party css library to a Directus module extension?

Tags: javascript, directus, lowcode

I am a newbie to Directus and I am building a custom module extension for Directus. I want to add tailwind css for styling. What is the proper way of importing it inside a Vuejs component of the extension?

I tried to install tailwind inside the extension folder and import it as a regular css import. but that didn't work.